# Where is the redstone dust in the tools section?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Where can I find the redstone dust in the creative inventory? I have Minecraft: Pocket Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Second row, second column (under the sword tab):

[image]

Picture from the [Pocket Edition Wiki](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Inventory)

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in the materials section of your inventory.

Comment: Can you elaborate some?  Where are materials?